# linux kernel: how can I copy files before panic?

Tags: file, file-io, linux-kernel, filesystems, embedded-linux

I have a file on tmpfs partition, which is updated alot.
I want to copy it to other partition (flash partition) before crash/reboot.

It is not an option to keep this file in the first place on the flash partition, 
because this flash has limited read/write life-cycle and I'm trying to avoid excessive read/writes to it.
too many writes will damage the flash, that is why the file is on tmpfs.

regrading reboot - I can modify the reboot process to copy before reboot - is there more neat way?

regrading crash - I don't know any way to do so. any ideas?
I know that that I should not mess with files from kernel space.

Thanks

Comment: Try adding the embedded-Linux tag your question may get some more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Only a Kernel panic occurs its possible that in-core data structures are already corrupted and unreliable. Ideally, your kernel is not expected to panic, if the version you are using is a stable and tested release. I would recommend capturing a `vmcore` using crash tool and working with the vendor on the root cause of the kernel panic.

However, if you are referring to an abrupt system shutdown dew to a power failure, etc which could possibly cause loss of the data / file stored in the memory, you could write a cron-job to sync the file to disk on intervals and tune the kernel on how frequently the dirty page get synced. Having said that, if the file you are writing to is quite important, why design it to be kept in the memory in the first place.

You should be syncing this file back to the disk once in every few seconds or in regular intervals. In this way you will not loose the complete data.

As the numbers of read/writes are heavy on the tmpfs file, it may be worth considering using a SSD for this purpose. Read about how file system transaction logs are configured to be stored on SSD drives.

Write a cron-job for syncing the tmpfs file to the SSD or disk in frequent intervals or when ever there are updates. You may want to consider changing some kernel tunables (such as, `vm.dirty_expire_centisecs=0`, `vm.dirty_background_ratio=0`) such that any dirty pages would get synced to the disk immediately. A word of caution, doing this would cause higher CPU% and I/O loads, as pages would synced to the disk frequently, although the data loss would be kept to minimal.

Comment: Use SSD is not an option. its embedded system with limited resources as I mentioned above. The system has only flash drive which has limited read/write lifecycle and Im trying to avoid excessive read/writes to it.
Your suggestion to use SSD drive is like to suggest to use stronger CPU to solve performance issue.

Comment: Its best if you can update the problem description with all this additional information, which would save a lot of time for others. You need to be clear when you mentioned "I want to copy it to other partition (flash partition) before crash/reboot." as to what kind of system / setup you are using.

Comment: Another thing copying file stored in the memory to any kind of non-volatile device once you system has crashed is never a good idea as the memory is already corrupt, so whatever need to be done it should be done in regular intervals while your system is stable.

Comment: Well, I didn't mention its embedded system but I did describe the limitation I have for not writing directly to disc. anyway I will add more info.
"once you system has crashed is never a good idea as the memory is already corrupt" - its not true on most of the cases. the system usually crash because NULL dereference or asserts and not due to memory corruption

Comment: @Nil I don't think your above statement is true, in an SMP scenario or even otherwise. When one of the processor is hit a NULL pointer deterrence whistle the other core is updating an in-core structure or a file. Do you think the contents of the file would be accurate from a crash dump?

Comment: I was not talking about SMP scenario. 
But even on SMP scenario, you might not get the last update to the file, but the entire file should be ok, isn't it?